# Setting root not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set (??), following [this site](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html),
and I succeeded up to setting root index to show `"hello Rails"`. In that tutorial,  the file `routes.rb` must be changed to:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.
  # ...
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   root to: "welcome#index"  #I just make this uncomment to set my hello rails show on index

 end
```

but it still does not work. Can anyone help me? I Use windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to delete the following static file:

```
public/index.html
```

Rails ships with a set of static files that provide basic functionality out-of-the-box. In the case of index.html, it's what's displayed by default when the root path is loaded. Until it's deleted, it'll continue to override your root route.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, now I can continue my practice. :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete `public/index.html`